# Why is there no memory overhead for an enum with a Vec<i64> variant?

Tags: memory, rust, enums

I am confused about why the size of Vec<i64> and VecEnum is the same in the following code:

```
pub enum VecEnum {
    Abc,
    Vec(Vec<i64>),
}

pub enum IntEnum {
    Abc,
    Int(i64),
}

pub fn main() {
    println!("IntEnum: {} bytes", core::mem::size_of::<IntEnum>());
    println!("i64: {} bytes", core::mem::size_of::<i64>());
    println!("VecEnum: {} bytes", core::mem::size_of::<VecEnum>());
    println!("Vec<i64>: {} bytes", core::mem::size_of::<Vec<i64>>());
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
IntEnum: 16 bytes 
i64: 8 bytes      
VecEnum: 24 bytes 
Vec<i64>: 24 bytes
```

For the i64 it behaves as expected: having an enum with a i64 variant requires extra space for the enum tag to be encoded. But why is this not the case for the Vec, which just consists of 3 8-byte values (ptr,len,capacity) of stack memory?

Can someone explain how the memory layout works here and what is happening under the hood?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have here is a so-called [Option-like enum](https://rust-lang.github.io/unsafe-code-guidelines/layout/enums.html#discriminant-elision-on-option-like-enums):

> An option-like enum is a 2-variant `enum` where:
>
> - the `enum` has no explicit `#[repr(...)]`, and
> - one variant has a single field, and
> - the other variant has no fields (the "unit variant").

(Basically, there's not a significant difference between `VecEnum` and `Option<Vec<i64>>`.)

Reading further from the above link, we can see that the compiler is able to effectively use "niches" (illegal values) of the payload type (`Vec<i64>`) as the enum's value for the payload-less variant.  This is called "discriminant elision."

The most obvious and well-known example of this is `Option<&T>`.  Since references cannot be null, the zero value is a niche that can be used to store the `None` variant.  This makes `&T` and `Option<&T>` have the same size.

The same thing is happening here.  The first field of `Vec<T>` is `RawVec<T>` (an internal type) whose first field is a (doc-hidden) type called [`Unique<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/ptr/unique.rs.html#35):

> A wrapper around a raw non-null `*mut T` ...

Well, if the compiler knows that `Unique<T>` can't be null, then a null pointer in this field is a niche of the `Vec<T>` type and so this can be used as a substitute discriminant, and discriminant elision is performed.

Note in particular that "all zeroes" is not the only valid niche.  Any bit-pattern that would be an illegal value for the payload type can be used.  For example, if the compiler knew of a type wrapping `f64` that guarantees the contained value cannot be `NaN`, then `Option<NotNanF64>` could represent `None` as the `NaN` bit-pattern.  However, "null pointer in a type that doesn't allow null pointers" is easily the most common niche.

Comment: Damn, who allowed the Rust Compiler to be smarter than me.